Combining filter values in a Dashboard in Salesforce Lightning
In Salesforce Lightning, dashboards, is there a way to combine two filter values as a third option?
From what I understand, a filter value can only include up to 1,333 characters including commas.  We have a filter value that is beyond that limit so, without having to create sub-groups, I wanted to see if there was a way to combine two filter values.
I'll attach screenshots (links).
For example,
the first filter value (Test 1) has a number of expected results separated by commas, as per screenshot Test 1 Filter Values
the second filter value (Test 2) has another set of expected results separated by commas.
With the idea that the third filter value (Test 1 & 2) is a combination of all the expected results from the other two filter values as per screenshot Attempt to Combine Test 1 & 2 Filters
